# Forgot what an arrow from an attribute in the same table means in RDBMS

Tags: database, rdbms

Here take a squiz at that,

http://gyazo.com/fef7b3899cb2d2785472af5d9d4b0c09

the arrow form SUPERSSN to SSN in EMPLOYEE

Forgot what that means, is it just telling me that it can also be used as a primary key?

IF you can shed light on this it'd be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means SUPERSSN has direct dependency on SSN.

SSN is underlined, and that signifies, SSN is a primary key.

And on whether :

> is it just telling me that it can also be used as a primary key

No it is not. It actually tells that SUPERSSN is dependent directly on PK, just like other columns or column-set of a table does. **But there is no sign, other columns can depend on SUPERSSN!**